# how to read external file from a class in the JAR

Tags: java, classloader

File Structure:

```
/web-project
   |
   |---/WEB-INF/a.jar
   |
   |---/META-INF/resources/b.properties
```

`A.class` which is located in `a.jar` wants to read `/META-INF/resources/b.properties`

I think that both a.jar and b.properties are under the same class loader (because they are in the same web context)

I've tried the following ways to try to achieve my purpose but not work.

```
InputStream is = null;
ClassLoader[] loaders = { Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(),
    ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), getClass().getClassLoader() };

ClassLoader currentLoader = null;
for (int i = 0; i < loaders.length; i++) {
    if (loaders[i] != null) {
        currentLoader = loaders[i];
        is = currentLoader.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/resources/b.properties");
        if (is != null) { // is is always null no matter what ways I used.
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea where I got mistakes.
Please guide me to the right path.
Thank you very much.

=====UPDATED=====

First of all , thanks for all people (especially @Ravi & @EJP) who comment, answer and discuss this question.

Below are what I've tried based on the discussion.

```
InputStream is = null;
URL url = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
is = A.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(url.getPath() + "../../../META-INF/resources/b.properites"); // is = null
is = new FileInputStream(url.getPath() + "../../../META-INF/resources/b.properites"); // is != null
```

It seems that I should use `FileInputStream` to get resources outside of the JAR instead of using `getResourceAsStream()`?

=====UPDATED 2=====

Eventually, I figured it out with the following solution.

```
context.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/resources/b.properties");
```

based on the prerequisite below:

a.jar/b.properties are in the same context

`A.class` can obtain the `ServletContext` object

Comment: Please post something we can run, or at least figure out how your program looks like. Which context this code is run in? Servlet initialization? Request handling?

Comment: so, how are you using class `A` from `jsp` or `Servlet` or any other class ?

Comment: Is the resource *in* the JAR file? If so, the code you posted, or any simplified version, should find it. If not, not.

Comment: @Howard Wang could you try what I posted and let us know, if that works ?

Comment: Either change your code to `A.class.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/resources/b.properties")`, or remove the initial slash (`/`) in your string argument.  Class.getResourceAsStream allows an initial slash;  ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream does not.

Comment: @Howard Wang I have updated the post, could you test and let us know ?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue by first validating the path for your jar file. You can execute following line of code and check the path

```
 getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

Since, you resource file is located outside of your jar file, you need to change the path ***relative*** to your jar file.

```
Properties mainProperties = new Properties();
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("<relative-path>/META-INF/resources/b.properties");
mainProperties.load(file);
file.close();
```

I have tested above code with below folder structure

```
/web-project
   |
   |---/WEB-INF/a.jar
   |
   |---/test/resources/b.properties
```

Comment: `getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` gives you the location *of the JAR file*. It has nothing whatsoever to do with the correct URI of a resource *within* the JAR file.

Comment: @EJP It seems like I used wrong words. I meant location of jar file actually.

Comment: @EJP Also, OP is asking to access resource which is *outside the jar file*. If you have missed this part of the question.

Comment: And  `getResourceAsStream()` is for resources *inside* the Jar file, and `META-INF` is inside the Jar file with that path, nothing in front of it, and certainly not the Jar file's own location. It's impossible. And he contradicts himself. He claims it is external, but in that case why would it be in `META-INF`? NB I'm curious as to how you tested something that doesn't work.

Comment: @EJP Agree. In my case it wasn't  META-INF folder. I created a folder as per his/her shown folder structure and then Tested.

Comment: 'His/her shown folder structure' *is* `META-INF`. What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: @EJP I think, there is no point of discussion, if OP himself/herself not clarifying it. Also, I meant to say, in my case I created some test folder in the same level to web-inf folder. And that means, web-inf and my test folder located under same folder. And, I placed the jar under web-inf folder.

Comment: Exactly, so you didn't create a folder called `META-INF/resources`, inside the JAR file, which is what the question is about, *and* you used `getResourceAsStream()` for a resource outside the JAR file, which doesn't work outside an IDE, so you haven't tested this answer in any useful way, so it remains nonsense.

Comment: @EJP thanks for your feedback. But, I will keep my post until OP respond. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that I should use `FileInputStream` to get resources outside of the JAR instead of using `getResourceAsStream()`?

Resources are *in* the JAR file, by definition. Anything outside it is not a resource but a file, and you should use `FileInputStream` or `FileReader` to read it. You can use

```
URL url = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

to get the location *of the JAR file*, so if you distribute the file in the same directory you just have to do a little path-mangling to get the path of the file from it.